# React Deployment error regarding my Manifest.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I seem to be getting this error on all my browsers in deployment? Not sure what the problem is.

error: `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error`

What is wrong with my code below?

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can guess ***start_url*** might be causing this issue, please find below my application **manifect.json** file

```js
{
  "short_name": "calculate_comps",
  "name": "Calculate Components",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "./index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
```

Comment: Hi Sarvesh, I added the `./index.html` but I seem to still be getting this error.

Comment: there might something you need to add in your base usrl

Comment: Where would I add this base url? I should note that I'm using Django as a backend that is serving my react static.